# Returning single row vaues from SQL Server stored procedure with LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I am trying to return a single row of data (multiple columns) from a stored procedure. I need to access the data from both columns of the returned row.

Obviously, I know I can do the following:

```
 foreach (var x in usp_GetNextLessonResults)
 {
    // MANIPULATE DATA HERE
 }
```

However, since there's only going to only be one row returned, I wasn't sure if there was an easier or better way to accomplish this.

I also tried adding two `OUTPUT` parameters in my stored procedure and tried to reference them as follows:

```
 int lessonId = 0;
 string importId = String.Empty;

 _db.usp_GetNextLesson(Request.QueryString["regid"], ref lessonId, ref importId)
```

However, this threw an error

> Argument 2 may not be passed with the ref keyword

on both of the output parameters in my C# code.

Does anyone have a better or more suggested solution for this problem?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_GetNextLesson
    (@RegistrationID VARCHAR(50),
     @LearnerLessonID INT OUTPUT,
     @ImportID VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- DECLARE @LearnerLessonID INT
    DECLARE @LearnerLessonOrder INT
    DECLARE @LearnerCourseID INT

    SELECT 
        @LearnerLessonID = [LearnerLesson].LearnerLessonID, 
        @LearnerLessonOrder = [LearnerLesson].[Order],
        @LearnerCourseID = [LearnerLesson].LearnerCourseID
    FROM 
        [dbo].[LearnerLesson] WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE 
        [LearnerLesson].RegistrationID = @RegistrationID

    DECLARE @NextLearnerLessonID INT

    SELECT TOP 1 
        @NextLearnerLessonID = [LearnerLesson].LearnerLessonID
    FROM 
        [dbo].[LearnerLesson] WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE 
        [LearnerLesson].LearnerCourseID = @LearnerCourseID
        AND [LearnerLesson].[Order] > @LearnerLessonOrder
    ORDER BY 
        [LearnerLesson].[Order]

    SELECT 
        [LearnerLesson].LearnerLessonID, [LearningObject].ImportID
    FROM 
        [dbo].[LearnerLesson] WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[LearningObject] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [LearnerLesson].LearningObjectID = [LearningObject].LearningObjectID
    WHERE 
        [LearnerLesson].LearnerLessonID = @NextLearnerLessonID
END
GO
```

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 0):

Make the lessonId as nullable int. Then you can use it as out variable.

`int? lessonId = 0;`